# R: How can I select a value from each row based on an index vector?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a matrix and an index vector. I would like to select a value from each row based on the index vector. For example, I would like to get `1  7 13  4 10` from the following matrix based on `ind`

```
XX <- matrix(1:15,nrow=5)
ind <- c(1,2,3,1,2)
> XX
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    6   11
[2,]    2    7   12
[3,]    3    8   13
[4,]    4    9   14
[5,]    5   10   15
```

Now my current way is not neat, I do something like below,

```
t(XX)[(0:(dim(XX)[1]-1))*dim(XX)[2]+ind]
```

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 3):

An option would be to use row/column indexing by `cbind`ing the row index (sequence of rows) with the column index ('ind') and extract the values of 'XX'

```
XX[cbind(seq_len(nrow(XX)), ind)]
#[1]  1  7 13  4 10
```

Comment: Super helpful answer! (+1) Would suggest making this simpler with `1:nrow(XX)`

Comment: @bob It may sound simpler, but it can have some issues when the number of rows is 0

Answer (score 1):

Using `apply` family:

```
    unlist(lapply(1:length(ind), function(x) XX[x, ind[x]]))
#[1]  1  7 13  4 10
```